# Getting error unable to get the unique property of worksheetfunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the unique values from a column of a table using the following:

```
Dim shops as Variant
shops = Application.WorksheetFunction.Unique(Worksheets("ALL_Shops").ListObjects("ALL_Shops").ListColumns("Names").DataBodyRange)
'Debug.Print shops
```

Getting an error: unable to get the unique property of worksheet-function class

Comment: The syntax is correct.  It assumes that the active workbook contains a sheet called "ALL_Shops", which contains a table called "ALL_Shops", which contains a column called "Names".  Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct. Also, checked the active workbook, that is correct too

Comment: Currently, the Unique function is only available on Excel for Microsoft 365, Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac, Excel for the web, Excel 2021, Excel 2021 for Mac, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone, Excel for Android tablets, Excel for Android phones.  Which version do you have?

Comment: Using Excel 2016. What other approach do I have then?

Comment: A Brute force way to do it: Loop all the values in the column and add them to a collection, a collection will automatically give you an error when adding a duplicate value, add a On Error Resume Next before the loop and an Err.Clear after the loop. This will leave you with a collection of unique values, now loop the collection and put them on an Array Variable.

Comment: Is the following valid: 
```Worksheets("ALL_Shops").ListObjects("ALL_Shops").ListColumns("Names").DataBodyRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, Unique:=True```

Comment: You're missing the CopyToRange argument for AdvancedFilter.

Comment: See the documentation for the AdvancedFilter [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144078)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue).

Comment: It says CopyTo Range argument that is optional. Also, this does not work on my excel 2016

Comment: It's not optional when you choose xlFilterCopy for the Action argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Using: `AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy Unique:=True` <strike>i get a "bugged" result with this</strike> test table:

[image]

VBA: (Edited to bring the entire column Range including Header to avoid first value duplication)

```
Sub arrayUniqueValTable2()
    Dim table As ListObject, columnRange As Range
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Set table = wk.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set columnRange = table.ListColumns("B").Range
    columnRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wk.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A15"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```

<strike>It returns a duplicate for the first value it finds:</strike>

| Result |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| A |
| C |
| D |

**Edit: ( As noted in the comment below by Tim, it is not a bug, it brings the first value twice assuming its the column name, editing the VBA code to include the Column Header on the Range resolves the duplicate issue)**

Alternative Brute Force Array, properly provides unique values:

VBA:

```
Sub arrayUniqueValTable()
    Dim table As ListObject, columnRange As Range
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim uniqueCol As New Collection
    Dim UniqueArray() As String
    Set wk = ThisWorkbook
    Set table = wk.Worksheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set columnRange = table.ListColumns("B").DataBodyRange
    Dim cell As Range
    'Loop all values in Range, add to Collection, ignore Errors (duplicates)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In columnRange
        uniqueCol.Add cell.Value, cell.Value
    Next
    'Clear Error in order to catch new ones.
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    'If the collection contains items, load them to an array
    If uniqueCol.Count > 0 Then
        'Re set array variable to correct size
        ReDim UniqueArray(1 To uniqueCol.Count)
        Dim rowStart As Long 'Row to start adding/pasting values
        rowStart = 10 'Next row will have the first value (11)
        For i = 1 To uniqueCol.Count
            'Load to Array Variable, must be loaded to array in order to use in a Range/Cell.Value
            UniqueArray(i) = uniqueCol(i)
            'Write to Column 'D' Starting on Row 11
            wk.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D" & (rowStart + i)).Value = UniqueArray(i)
        Next i
        MsgBox "Unique Items in Array: " & UBound(UniqueArray)
    Else
        'No values were found in the column
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not "bugged" - AdvancedFilter always assumes the first item in a list is a header, and that header is copied to the output range.  `Set columnRange = table.ListColumns("B").Range` will pick up the actual column header and use that, not the first item in the column data.

Comment: I tried your brute force method and it works. While trying the Advanced Filter way (after your edits), I get another error saying the extract range has a missing or invalid field name on this line ```columnRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wk.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A15"), Unique:=True```

Comment: @MJ  Have you set the range properly: `Dim columnRange As Range: Set columnRange = Worksheets("ALL_Shops").ListObjects("ALL_Shops").ListColumns("Names").Range`? Also, cell `A15` in `Sheet2` has to be empty or have the same header i.e. `Names`. And I think every cell below the header cell has to be empty (not quite sure).

Comment: I set the range correctly. A15 wasn't empty. Works now

Answer (score 0):

### Get Unique Values Using a Dictionary

**Excel (Microsoft 365)**

- The two columns to the right of the table and their formulas illustrate how `UNIQUE` works.
- To ignore errors and blanks, you can additionally use `TOCOL` (not yet available as a worksheet function) with its 2nd argument's parameter set to `3`,  the point being that the code below mimics this behavior.

[image]

**VBA**

- The dictionary was made for this.
- Note that this doesn't work on a Mac.

```vb
Sub UniqueColumn()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = wb.Sheets("All_Shops") _
        .ListObjects("All_Shops").ListColumns("Names").DataBodyRange
    
    Dim Shops(), IsInvalid As Boolean
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        IsInvalid = True
    Else
        ' Return the values from the single-column range
        ' in a 2D one-based single-column array.
        Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
        If rCount = 1 Then
            ReDim Shops(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Shops(1, 1) = rg.Value
        Else
            Shops = rg.Value
        End If
        ' Write the unique values from the array to a dictionary.
        Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' ignore case
        Dim Key, r As Long
        For r = 1 To rCount
            Key = Shops(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then ' exclude errors
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                    dict(Key) = Empty
                    ' The line above is short for:
                    'If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then dict.Add Key, Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next r
        If dict.Count = 0 Then ' only errors and blanks
            IsInvalid = True
        Else
            ' Return the unique values from the dictionary
            ' in another 2D one-based single-column array (reusing variables).
            rCount = dict.Count
            r = 0
            ReDim Shops(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
            For Each Key In dict.Keys
                r = r + 1
                Shops(r, 1) = Key
            Next Key
        End If
    End If
    
    If IsInvalid Then
        MsgBox "No (valid) data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Continue using 'Shops'.
    ' In the continuation, instead of 'UBound(Shops, 1)',
    ' we could have used 'rCount' or even 'r'.
    
    ' Write the names to a range in another worksheet.
    'wb.Sheets("Another").Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Shops, 1)).Value = Shops
    
    ' Print the names to the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    For r = 1 To UBound(Shops, 1)
        Debug.Print Shops(r, 1)
    Next r
        
End Sub
```

**Results in the Immediate window (`Ctrl+G`)**

```
NOAH
Liam
Emma
OLIVIA
```